# Maven 2, Liquibase and dbDoc

Tags: maven-2, liquibase

I'd like to generate liquibase's dbdoc as part of my maven site build, but I cannot figure out how to do this. My thoughts were to add maven-antrun-plugin to the reporting section of the pom, but I cannot have an  node under plugin in the reporting section. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the [Maven LiquiBase Plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven) so either create your own report plugin or use the [dbDoc Ant Task](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/dbdoc_ant_task) and the Maven AntRun Plugin to generate the documentation under `target/site/`.

In the later case, bind the plugin on one of the phases of the [Site Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) (this will require some testing but I think that `pre-site`, `site` or `post-site` would be ok) and add an entry in the left menu in the [site descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this for all three site phases and the ant task won't run (no errors reported). I am successful in generating the dbDoc when I set the phase to process-resources however.

Comment: @Duncan I suspect that you aren't running `mvn site` (`process-resources` is not part of the site lifecycle).

Comment: true, my response was confusing. What I meant was that the dbDoc generates when i run mvn clean install and the phase is (process-resources). However when I change it to (pre-site, site or post-site) dbDoc is not generated when I run mvn site. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own reports plugin, more information here:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Write+your+own+report+plugin